# Change an interval

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do `setInterval`, then after 180 times it runs, slow down the interval time?

Basically after about 15 minutes I would like the timer to only run once every minute, then after about an hour set the interval to run once every hour. I am hoping that there is a way I can do this without having to embed a `setInterval` within a `setInterval` within a `setInterval`.

```
var c = 0;
var interval = 5000;
var timer;
timer = setInterval(function(){
    checkActivity();
    c++;
    if(c > 180){
        interval = 60000;
    }
}, interval);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var c = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    checkActivity();
    c++;
    if( c == 180) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(arguments.callee,60000);
    }
},5000);
```